# How to move an image in html & css

Tags: html, css

I'm using embedded images from Getty images, i want to move on picture to be below the other one.

Here is the code for the first image

```html
<div class="getty embed image" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:11px;width:100%;max-width:506px;">
  <div style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;">
    <a href="http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/73667906" target="_blank" style="color:#a7a7a7;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal !important;border:none;display:inline-block;">Embed from Getty Images</a>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:0;padding:66.403162% 0 0 0;width:100%;">
  <iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/73667906?et=x-Pax92QRbhQPd71Hr6VwA&tld=com&viewMoreLink=on&sig=_RFZUtF6qBuiB6YWp3Ycrg9GFwMLvAYqV15y4_Cjejk=&caption=true" width="506" height="336" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%; margin:0;" ></iframe>
  </div>
  <p style="margin:0;"></p>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the second image

```html
<div class="getty embed image" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:11px;width:100%;max-width:478px;">
   <div style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;">
    <a href="http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/500284629" target="_blank" style="color:#a7a7a7;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal !important;border:none;display:inline-block;">Embed from Getty Images</a>
   </div>
   <div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:0;padding:75.104603% 0 0 0;width:100%;">
     <iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/500284629?et=97hObt6TTeV4YPmb9EWgpA&tld=com&viewMoreLink=on&sig=6orn1zgKVOtb4oFXLEM8vZ1xArk_b24dCn9H2L6Qzz4=&caption=true" width="478" height="359" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:0;left:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0;" ></iframe>
   </div>
  <p style="margin:0;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is to add the: `<br>` html tag between the divs containing the images.
This will place a line break between the images.

Comment: No problem @noct27

Comment: If you need to add more css style to your images in the future I suggest making an external style sheet like @LucasDavidFerrero said.